# Multiple instances of a singleton class... very strange behavior

Tags: java, android, singleton

I have a class which implements the Singleton pattern. I need an instance of this class in an Activity and in a fragment (hosted by the activity).

The strange is that, also if the activity is the first to create the instance of the singleton class, when I try to retrieve that instance from the fragment it creates another instance...

The following is the code of the singleton class:

```
public class NotificationCenter {
    private NotificationCenter() {

    }

// useless for this question
    private class MyObservable extends Observable {
        @Override
        protected void setChanged() {
            super.setChanged();
        }
    }

    // useless for this question
    private class MyObserver implements Observer {
        String name;
        Notificable notificable;

        public MyObserver(String name, Notificable notificable) {
            this.name = name;
            this.notificable = notificable;
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
            notificable.notificationReceived(name, data);
        }       
    }

    private static NotificationCenter defaultCenter = null;
    private HashMap<String, MyObservable> observables;

    public static synchronized NotificationCenter defaultCenter() {
        if (defaultCenter==null) {
            defaultCenter = new NotificationCenter();
            defaultCenter.observables = new HashMap<String, MyObservable>();
        }

        return defaultCenter;
    }

    public void addObserver(String notification, Notificable notificable) {
        MyObservable observable = observables.get(notification);
        if (observable==null) {
            observable = new MyObservable();
            observables.put(notification, observable);
        }
        MyObserver observer = new MyObserver(notification, notificable);
        observable.addObserver(observer);
    }

    public void removeObserver(String notification, Observer observer) {
        MyObservable observable = observables.get(notification);
        if (observable!=null) {         
            observable.deleteObserver(observer);
        }
    }       

    public void postNotification(String notification, final Object object) {
        final MyObservable observable = observables.get(notification);
        if (observable!=null) {
            observable.setChanged();
            observable.notifyObservers(object);
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to consider something which I do not?
All the calls to the defaultCenter() method are made on the main thread.

Comment: How do you know it's different?

Comment: because I see from the debugger that it passes two times from the creation instruction (instance = new Singleton();)  and because of other considerations. I'm SURE it creates the singleton instance two times

Comment: Unless you are messing up with class loaders, it can only be a thread safety issue...

Comment: I call the getInstance method in two very different moments (also after minutes). Also I call the getInstance method more than once in the activity and then when I call it inside the fragment it creates the instance again... I know you are thinking I'm stupid, but I know what I'm saying, just it's very strange and is the first time I meet this problem after years of developing in Java.

Comment: Why don't you just make the method synchronized: `public synchronized static Singleton getInstance()` and see if you still get the issue? (and you make the other method synchronized too) - You could also print the thread name in the constructor to verify your assumption. But basically, in a single threaded environment, your class can't execute the constructor twice, so it has to be something due to threading...

Comment: can you use the debugger to follow up the thread chain as to where it all starts when the getinstance is called by the Activity and when called by the fragment?

Comment: I do not use the synchronized because I'm quite sure there is not the risk of calling that method twice in a very short time. However, tomorrow I'll try at job

Comment: @Massimo Short time is irrelevant - without proper synchronization, the changes made by one thread may *never* be viewed by another thread...

Comment: Yes, but it is strange that the problem always appears. Furthermore if it was a safety problem it would appear also if I call the getInstance method more than once on the same activity; instead the problem appears only when I call getInstance inside the fragment (regardless of how much time has passed)

Comment: @Massimo I'm not familiar with android's threading model but it could happen if the activity and the fragment don't run on the same thread - or if you call `getInstance` within a listener that is called from another thread for example.

Comment: This is my first thought, but unfortunately I discovered that both calls have been executed on the same thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, your code didn't even compile

```
 map.put(k,v); // not add
```

**Second**, I added a `println()` in your constructor

```
private HashMap<String, String> map;
private Singleton() {
    System.out.println("Singleton Constructor");
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

**Third**, I tested it -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Singleton one = Singleton.getInstance();
    Singleton two = Singleton.getInstance();
    if (one == two) {
        System.out.println("One instance");
    }
}
```

The results were

```
Singleton Constructor
One instance
```

Please post your actual code if you're sue about the error (because your code here was clearly incorrect).

Comment: I said there are not problems if I call the getInstance method two or more times inside the activity. The problem is when I call the getInstance the first time on the fragment after I called it one or more times inside the activity.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, your code is not thread safe. Unless the Singleton is expensive to instantiate, then simply initialise it up front.

```
class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
```